# Does rails still lock up when sending large file downloads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading

What is the recommended way to send a file download using rails 3.2.13? I read [this article](http://www.therailsway.com/2009/2/22/file-downloads-done-right/) which indicates that rails does not handle downloads well:

> Whether you’re using mongrel, fastcgi or passenger you have a limited
>   number of rails processes available to handle application requests.
>   When one of your users makes a request, you want to know that you
>   either have a process free to handle the request, or that one will
>   become free in short order. If you don’t, users will face an agonizing
>   wait for pages to load, or see their browser sessions timeout
>   entirely.

Is this still true with rails 3.2.13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "yes", rails still locks down the application worker for the duration of a file transfer.

On the up side, the same article you linked offers a solution through x-sendfile or x-accel-redirect, where the application passes the file transfer back to the web server. This still works, and is as efficient as any of rails' competitors.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure before implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is best practice to serve assets and large files through a separate CDN.

This way, your application server does not have to handle the downloads by itself. Instead, it is delegated to ngnix or apache.

Comment: Sure, but that's out of scope for this project. Thanks.